# How to play video that comes in Google Plus Activity Feed

Tags: video, android-activity, feed, google-plus

I am getting following attachment url for ObjectType=video element in the google plus activity feed, I have tried many player like jwplayer and html5 video tag to play but none of them worked in my php/Yii webiste.

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-z225_3Ru51c/TvhGR83cjbI/AAAAAAAADyY/heep44ZpgkM/1665478915699_10120.mp4

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple URLs associated with a video attachment to a Google+ activity. It appears that the one you've found is actually the thumbnail image (despite the misleading file extension).

Try experimenting with the other URLs contained in the attachment list associated with this activity.

Here's an example of an activity (id z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i) that and it's associated attachment. In the case of this activity you're probably most interested in the 'embed' url.

```
"attachments": [{
  "objectType": "video",
  "displayName": "Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up",
  "content": "Music video by Rick Astley performing Never Gonna Give You Up. YouTube view counts pre-VEVO: 2,573,462 (C) 1987 PWL",
  "url": "http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ&hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1",
  "image": {
    "url": "http://images0-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=focus&gadget=a&resize_h=100&url=http%3A%2F%2Fytimg.googleusercontent.com%2Fvi%2FdQw4w9WgXcQ%2Fdefault.jpg",
    "type": "image/jpeg"
  },
  "embed": {
    "url": "http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ&hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1",
    "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash"
  }
}]
```

Comment: if its a youtube url then its works fine. But if you upload a video file yourself then it is causing issue, I am wondering if this is an permission issue or so.